# Webkit vs. Firefox vs. Opera text-shadow issue

Tags: firefox, webkit, css

I seem to have an issue where Firefox is displaying a blurred text shadow of 0.75 opacity just fine on white background, but in Webkit and Opera it's too dark/crisp.  Who is right?  What gives?  And how should I attempt to solve it? Thanks.

Notes:

Here's an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfcox/vpjZa/)

Actually, it seems like the issue might be in the choice of image processing filter.  The fire fox version seems the blurriest, followed then by Opera's and then Chrome/Safari (Webkit).  It almost looks like the Webkit browsers are using some sort of box filter to do their blurring, whereas  Firefox is using something smoother.  The shadow seems just too crisp in Webkit.

Comment: This is just the way it works in different browsers... Plus if you're using webkit in windows it tends to look crisper than in mac.

Comment: you should not worry about these things. they all support it, it's up to them to implement it correctly. they ARE different browsers after all.

Comment: The problem was using a different (actual webfont) the shadow just makes the whole typeface look ugly and hard to read (this was brought up by my client).  I do have the option of lightening my shadow (which I will), but I never really understood the issue until I realized I was staring at it in Firefox, not in Chrome/Safari.  It's kinda silly to say "I shouldn't  worry about it" when these implementation details *do indeed matter*.  That's like telling me not to worry about font anti-aliasing.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not even sure what behavior *is* correct or if it was just unspecified in the requirements.  I was hoping to not have to dig through the specs and glean what I could from my fellow developers.  But since this seems to be a minor concern, I may just have to.

Comment: Well, the point here is, before showing anything to the client, do make sure that it's readable in all required browsers. All browsers follow the box-shadow spec, they just use different methods to achieve the same result, but obviously, with minor differences. From my experience Firefox always has the best output for css3 stuff. Fonts look nicer and shadows and border-radius look smoother. On the other hand Chrome, at least on Windows, always looks a little bit worse but hey, webkit has more features than any other engine.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your problem in order to fix that on chrome and opera you must set blur radius on a higher value in order to have same result on those three browsers. I know that because I use a box-shadow on Firefox and Chrome and I noticed that.

check this live example:  http://css3generator.com/

firefox: text-shadow: 1px 10px 19px #050505;
chrome and opera: 1px 10px 29px #050505;

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how I'd set different blur radii for the different browsers without some major trickery.  I'm not sure that my suggestion of adding multiple shadows isn't better, although it may more processor intensive (esp. if I start animating the elements, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#changes (W3C Working Draft 19 January 2012)

> A number of less-stable features have been deferred to Level 4:  ...
>
> ...
>
> - the spread radius on ‘text-shadow’

So the meaning hasn't been specified. Go figure.

In any case, I also (re)discovered that `text-shadow` accepts a comma delimited list, so I suppose if I wanted to manually blur it further, If I originally had

```
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

I could maybe do something like

```
 text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1875),
   4px 6px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1875),
   6px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1875),
   6px 6px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1875);
```

adding shadows as necessary.